# How to Use Localized Resources in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint, cdn, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have the following section defined in my config.json:

```
  "externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    }
  },
  "localizedResources": {
    "SimpleContactFormWebPartStrings": "lib/webparts/simpleContactForm/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
```

In my write-manifests.json, I have the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
  "cdnBasePath": "https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/{super long ID for the CDN}/PublicCDN/SimpleContactFormWebPart/"
}
```

However, when I deploy my site using `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` I get the error!

I have also tried the following values for **cdnBasePath**:

- https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SubSite/SiteAssets/PublicCDN/
- https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SubSite/PublicCDN/

Please note: "PublicCDN" is a folder under the SiteAssets library.

**Technical Details**

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
>   ***Failed to load component "63fefa07-d133-4d8b-beba-e4a961675cad" (SimpleContactFormWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load URL
>   'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/avvenireinc.sharepoint.com/sites/14480077efdd98d1f7ac72f606b8b39cd9fcec4dbae7db146cdded624b48b5c09c1eee47/PublicCDN/SimpleContactFormWebPart/simplecontactformwebpart-simplecontactformwebpartstrings_en-us_42a0f6681da2dc33b87df83d67355874.js'
>   for resource 'SimpleContactFormWebPartStrings' in component
>   '63fefa07-d133-4d8b-beba-e4a961675cad' (SimpleContactFormWebPart).
>   There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS
>   certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.

How can I define my CDN paths so that SharePoint can find the localization file!?

**Edit:** After removing the localization file and it's references, I now get the following error which seems to indicate that nothing is actually being deployed when I run `gulp bundle --ship`:

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: ***Failed to load component
>   "63fefa07-d133-4d8b-beba-e4a961675cad" (SimpleContactFormWebPart).
>   Original error: ***Failed to load URL
>   'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SubSite/SiteAssets/PublicCDN/simple-contact-form-web-part_cea1554eb41a7c3ea6a3ee01291a7e17.js'
>   for resource 'simple-contact-form-web-part' in component
>   '63fefa07-d133-4d8b-beba-e4a961675cad' (SimpleContactFormWebPart).
>   There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS
>   certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using CDN reference, i would recommend to use `SPComponentLoader`. Below is example with jQuery (replace your actual CDN path here): 
First import the module `import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader'`
Now add this line to load your jQuery. This is asynchronous call
 `SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')`

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript(
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'
    ).then(($: any) => {
      sayHello();
//access jQuery object with window['jQuery'] or declare variable inside your class as public jQuery: any, and assign $ as this.jQuery = $
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it seems that jQuery and Bootstrap load correctly; it's the localized files on the SharePoint CDN that are not loading correctly.  How do you recommend I load them?

Comment: Can I know what is that file that you are accessing? is it related to your organization or public SP ?

Comment: Yes, it's the file listed in my config with the path, "lib/webparts/simpleContactForm/loc/{locale}.js" where *locale* is "en_us."

Comment: As I know this is not possible. But can you tell me what this file will do? Seems you are using language specific file. This will be handled automatically by SPFx framework.

Comment: This is a just a standard locale file as described by the MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint).  This issue sounds seems to be similar to: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/How-do-we-deploy-SPFx-Web-Parts-to-a-Private-CDN-on-O365/td-p/69362